# How to delete a google tag manager container?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I can not find how to delete a container, I did not find the delete button when I access the container settings,can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the admin section for your container, open "Container setting" and click in the menu with the three little dots on the right. If you have the necessary permissions (guaranteed if you created the container yourself) there will be a delete option.

[image: gtm container delete option]